# Segue Not performed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a login view controller at the start of the app. Then once the user login is successful I am taking the user to a view which has a table view inside it. I have embedded the table view inside a navigation controller. I have a segue which pushes user to the detail view. However as soon as I click on the row cell, I get the following error.

```
'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'Event Details'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.''
```

But as I said above, there is a navigationview controller which embeds the table view. Whats causing this error?

the flow of the app is as follows

```
'->Login View     NavigatinViewController->(View with a table View inside)->Details'
```

Comment: post the code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EventDetails" sender:nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you may be missing a view controller.

Specifically, you should have something that resembles:

> Login View > Navigation Controller > Table View Controller > Detail View Controller

Assuming you are creating a storyboard, the navigation controller can be easily added by selecting the table view controller and choosing Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller.

Alternatively, if you want the navigation controller solely for a table view that is embedded within a view controller object, I recommend creating a container view in the view controller to display the table view and associated navigation controller.

To accomplish the latter, drag a container object into the view controller and size it to fit the table view that you want to display. Delete the view controller that the container view automatically creates.

Next, create a table view controller and segue to it from the container view. This segue will be an 'embed' segue. Lastly, you can then embed the table view controller you just created in a navigation controller and add the push segue from the table view controller to the detail view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think here you not use `UINavigationController` as a `RootViewController`.. and you use `UIViewController` as a rootViewController.. so may be this problem with this error

Just try to Follow this steps for the output..

1. Drag a new navigation controller into your storyboard - it will by default be attached to a tableview controller
2. Delete the tableview controller Right click on the navgiation controller, and connect the "Root View Controller" property to your existing view controller
3. Move the entry point arrow from your view controller to the root view controller

**UPDATE:**

see this example which through you can put validation and clearly push in your detailview...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = 
          segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailsViewController 
          *playerDetailsViewController = 
            [[navigationController viewControllers] 
              objectAtIndex:0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by existing view controller? the login view or the view which has the table view?

Comment: see this whole tutorial which i follow for storyboard dude.. also you findout many things for storyboard from it and laos demos also.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2 :)

Comment: As I see it, The UINavigation controller is the root view controller

Comment: @ravijimagna hey i think something wrong going with segue name not give the space between the segue name dude and set first character small not capital like.. "eventDetails" try this dude...

Comment: @ravijimagna see the updated answer dude also add navigationcontroller when you push from there dude.. hope this help you... :)